# I was trying to do conditional feilds fo the HTML form, And unable to do and need to know how to achieve

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was trying to achieve to show the fields when a user select a radio option and if he choose other it has to show another text box

Let me be clear

from below code if user choose "chaitanya school" option it should show the "Enter EPN number" and hide the "school name field"

if user choose other the "enter school name" has to be shown and "EPN number" has to be hidden

Code i used to achieve

```
<!--Single Line-->
<label>First Name of the student 
<em>*</em>
</label>
<input  type="text" name="SingleLine" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
<!--Single Line-->
<label>Last Name of the student 
<em>*</em>
</label>
<input  type="text" name="SingleLine2" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
<!--Date-->
<label>Date of Birth 
<em>*</em>
</label>
<input type="text" name="Date" value="" maxlength="25"/><label>dd-MMM-yyyy</label>
<!--Dropdown-->
<label>Class studying in school
<em>*</em>
</label>
<select name="Dropdown"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
<option value="V">V</option>
<option value="VI">VI</option>
<option value="VII">VII</option>
<option value="VIII">VIII</option>
<option value="IX">IX</option>
</select>
<!--Single Line-->
<label>Parent/Guardian Name 
<em>*</em>
</label>
<input  type="text" name="SingleLine1" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
<!--Email-->
<label>Email 
<em>*</em>
</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="Email" value="" fieldType=9 />
<!--Phone-->
<label>Phone
<em>*</em>
</label>
<input type="text" compname="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber_countrycode" phoneFormat="isCountryCodeEnabled=false maxlength="20" value="" fieldType=11 id="international_PhoneNumber_countrycode" />
<label>Number</label>
<!--Dropdown-->
<label>Mode of Exam
</label>
<select name="Dropdown1"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
<option value="Online">Online</option>
<option value="Offline">Offline</option>
</select>
<!--Dropdown-->
<label>Exam Dates
<em>*</em>
</label>
<select name="Dropdown2"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
<option value="Dec&#x20;4,&#x20;2021">Dec 4, 2021</option>
<option value="Dec&#x20;18,&#x20;2021">Dec 18, 2021</option>
<option value="Jan&#x20;22,&#x20;2022">Jan 22, 2022</option>
<option value="Jan&#x20;29,&#x20;2022">Jan 29, 2022</option>
</select>
<!--Radio-->
<label>School studying in
</label>
<input type="radio" id="Radio_1" name="Radio" value="chaitanya School">
<label name="Radio1" for="Radio_1" >Chaitanya&#x20;School</label>
<input type="radio" id="Radio_2" name="Radio" value="Other">
<label name="Radio2" for="Radio_2" >Other</label>
<!--Number-->
<label>EPN 
</label>
<input data-show-if="Radio1" data-hide-if="Radio2" type="text" name="Number" value="" maxlength="18"/>
<!--Single Line-->
<label>School Name 
</label>
<input data-show-if="Radio2" data-hide-if="Radio1"  type="text" name="SingleLine3" value=""  fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
<button type="submit"><em>Submit</em></button></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CSS element1~element2 Selector`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp) and [`CSS Attribute Selectors`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```
<style>
[data-show-if] {
    display: none;
}

#Radio_1:checked ~ [data-show-if="Radio1"] {
    display: block;
}
#Radio_2:checked ~ [data-show-if="Radio2"] {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

check snippet below:

```html
<style>
    [data-show-if] {
        display: none;
    }

    #Radio_1:checked ~ [data-show-if="Radio1"] {
        display: block;
    }
    #Radio_2:checked ~ [data-show-if="Radio2"] {
        display: block;
    }

</style>
<!--Single Line-->
<label>First Name of the student
    <em>*</em>
</label>
<input  type="text" name="SingleLine" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
<!--Single Line-->
<label>Last Name of the student
    <em>*</em>
</label>
<input  type="text" name="SingleLine2" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
<!--Date-->
<label>Date of Birth
    <em>*</em>
</label>
<input type="text" name="Date" value="" maxlength="25"/><label>dd-MMM-yyyy</label>
<!--Dropdown-->
<label>Class studying in school
    <em>*</em>
</label>
<select name="Dropdown"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
    <option value="V">V</option>
    <option value="VI">VI</option>
    <option value="VII">VII</option>
    <option value="VIII">VIII</option>
    <option value="IX">IX</option>
</select>
<!--Single Line-->
<label>Parent/Guardian Name
    <em>*</em>
</label>
<input  type="text" name="SingleLine1" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
<!--Email-->
<label>Email
    <em>*</em>
</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="Email" value="" fieldType=9 />
<!--Phone-->
<label>Phone
    <em>*</em>
</label>
<input type="text" compname="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber_countrycode" phoneFormat="isCountryCodeEnabled=false maxlength="20" value="" fieldType=11 id="international_PhoneNumber_countrycode" />
<label>Number</label>
<!--Dropdown-->
<label>Mode of Exam
</label>
<select name="Dropdown1"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
    <option value="Online">Online</option>
    <option value="Offline">Offline</option>
</select>
<!--Dropdown-->
<label>Exam Dates
    <em>*</em>
</label>
<select name="Dropdown2"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
    <option value="Dec&#x20;4,&#x20;2021">Dec 4, 2021</option>
    <option value="Dec&#x20;18,&#x20;2021">Dec 18, 2021</option>
    <option value="Jan&#x20;22,&#x20;2022">Jan 22, 2022</option>
    <option value="Jan&#x20;29,&#x20;2022">Jan 29, 2022</option>
</select>
<!--Radio-->
<label>School studying in
</label>
<input type="radio" id="Radio_1" name="Radio" value="chaitanya School">
<label name="Radio1" for="Radio_1" >Chaitanya&#x20;School</label>
<input type="radio" id="Radio_2" name="Radio" value="Other">
<label name="Radio2" for="Radio_2" >Other</label>
<!--Number-->
<label>EPN
</label>
<input data-show-if="Radio1" data-hide-if="Radio2" type="text" name="Number" value="" maxlength="18"/>
<!--Single Line-->
<label>School Name
</label>
<input data-show-if="Radio2" data-hide-if="Radio1"  type="text" name="SingleLine3" value=""  fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
<button type="submit"><em>Submit</em></button></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I used jquery to get the checkbox change event by its id and perform show hide on another element it's quite simple.

```
  $("#Radio_1").change(function(){
     $("#shcoolName,#shlabel").hide();
    });
```

and for on-page load select any radio button you have to use this

```
$("#Radio_1").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
```

and you can get a dropdown change event using the below code

```
 $("#DllExamMode").change(function(){
    if(this.value=="Online")
    {
        $("#DllExam").val("Dec 4, 2021");
    }else
    {
        $("#DllExam").val("Jan 29, 2022");
    }   
});
```

check this working demo it's easier to understand.

```html
<form action='https://forms.zohopublic.com/thepupil/form/super100/formperma/Gf5sDFJYEy6GYaKsiAkv9rCl1IpYMqijNZwkZng4b3Q/htmlRecords/submit' name='form' id='form' method='POST' accept-charset='UTF-8' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="hidden" name="zf_referrer_name" value=""><!-- To Track referrals , place the referrer name within the " " in the above hidden input field -->
<input type="hidden" name="zf_redirect_url" value=""><!-- To redirect to a specific page after record submission , place the respective url within the " " in the above hidden input field -->
<input type="hidden" name="zc_gad" value=""><!-- If GCLID is enabled in Zoho CRM Integration, click details of AdWords Ads will be pushed to Zoho CRM -->
    
    
    <h2 class="fromhead">Get rewarded for your smartness!</h2>
    <p></p>
    <br>

    <section class="ep">
        <section class="column">
            <label>First Name of the student <em>*</em>
            </label>
            <input  type="text" name="SingleLine" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
            </section>
            <section class="column">
            <label>Last Name of the student <em>*</em>
            </label>
            <input  type="text" name="SingleLine2" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
        </section>
    </section>

    <br><br>
    
    <section class="ep">
        <section class="column">
            <label>Date of Birth 
            <em>*</em>
            </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ex: 11-Nov-2005" name="Date" value="" maxlength="25"/>
        </section>
        
    <!--Phone-->
        <section class="column">
            <label>Class currently studying in
                <em>*</em>
                </label>
                <select name="Dropdown"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
                <option value="V">V</option>
                <option value="VI">VI</option>
                <option value="VII">VII</option>
                <option value="VIII">VIII</option>
                <option value="IX">IX</option>
                </select>
        </section>
    </section>
    <br><br>

    <section class="ep">
        <section class="column">
            <label>Parent/Guardian Name 
            <em>*</em>
            </label>
            <input  type="text" name="SingleLine1" value="" fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
        </section>

        <section class="column">
            <!--Dropdown-->
            <label>Phone Number 
            <em>*</em>
            </label>
            <input type="text" compname="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber_countrycode" phoneFormat="1" isCountryCodeEnabled=false maxlength="20" value="" fieldType=11 id="international_PhoneNumber_countrycode" />
            <br>
    </section>

        
    </section>

    
    
    <section class="ep ep4">

        <section class="column">
            <label>Email 
            <em>*</em>
            </label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="Email" value="" fieldType=9 />
        </section>

        <section class="column">
            <label>Mode of Exam
                <em>*</em>
                </label>
                <select name="Dropdown1" id="DllExamMode"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
                <option value="Online">Online</option>
                <option value="Offline">Offline</option>
                </select>
        </section>

        
    </section>

    <br>
    <section class="ep ep4">

        
            <label>Exam Dates
                <em>*</em>
                </label>
                <select name="Dropdown2" id="DllExam"><option selected="true" value="-Select-">-Select-</option>
                <option value="Dec&#x20;4,&#x20;2021">Dec 4, 2021</option>
                <option value="Dec&#x20;18,&#x20;2021">Dec 18, 2021</option>
                <option value="Jan&#x20;22,&#x20;2022">Jan 22, 2022</option>
                <option value="Jan&#x20;29,&#x20;2022">Jan 29, 2022</option>
                </select>
        
    

    </section>

    <section class"ep">
    
        <!--Radio-->
        <label>School studying in
        </label><br><br>
        <input class"r1" type="radio" id="Radio_1" name="Radio" value="The Pupil Saveetha Eco School">
        <label name="Radio1" for="Radio_1" >The&#x20;Pupil&#x20;Saveetha&#x20;Eco&#x20;School</label>
        <input class"r2" type="radio" id="Radio_2" name="Radio" value="Other">
        <label name="Radio2" for="Radio_2" >Other</label>
        
    </section>


    <section class="ep ep5">
        
        <!--Number-->
        <label id="lblepn">EPN Number
        </label>
        <input data-show-if="Radio1"  id="epn" data-hide-if="Radio2" type="text" name="Number" value="" maxlength="18"/>
        <!--Single Line-->

        <label id="shlabel">School Name 
        </label>
        <input data-show-if="Radio2" data-hide-if="Radio1" id="shcoolName" type="text" name="SingleLine3" value=""  fieldType=1 maxlength="255" />
        </section>
        </section>
    </section>


    
    <!--Dropdown-->
    

    
    
    <button type="submit"><em>Submit</em></button>

</form>
    
    <style>
    #international_PhoneNumber_countrycode {
        width: 94%;
    }
    #fn {
        width: 96% !important;
    }
    #ln {
        width: 96% !important;
    }
    #Radio_2 {
    width: 6% !important;
    }
    #Radio_1 {
        width:3% !important;
    }
    .ep.ep5 {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
button {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Radio_1").change(function(){
 $("#shcoolName,#shlabel").hide();
 $("#epn,#lblepn").show();
});
$("#Radio_2").change(function(){
 $("#shcoolName,#shlabel").show();
 $("#epn,#lblepn").hide();
});
$("#DllExamMode").change(function(){
if(this.value=="Online")
{
$("#DllExam").val("Dec 4, 2021");
}else
{
$("#DllExam").val("Jan 29, 2022");
}   
});
$("#Radio_1").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
});
</script>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: It works thanks for help, but when page loads both the fields are visible , until once we click on any other radio button

Comment: ok for that you have to select at least one on page load.

Comment: again for that please tell how to select the first radio button selected

Comment: ok wait i update this code.

Comment: thanks for the helping have you updated the code

Comment: @Jobs please check updated code.

Comment: hey one more thing when we click on mode of exam drop down , it should show some other fields if online is selected

Comment: [link](https://codeshare.io/qPpBox)

Please check the above code in this when we select exam mode as online it should show one set of dates, it they choose it should show one set of dates , which i have no clue please show me how to

Comment: please help withe the above code

Comment: @Jobs Please check i Updated code.